# Winform application to talk to service

Tags: c#, wcf, service

I need to write a service in C# that will always run on a PC even if no one is logged in. I need to write a c# winform application that will auto-run when a user logs in and allows the user to interact with the service.My proposed solution is to build a WCF server into the service and write a WCF client into the winform application. This will then allow interaction between the Winform application and the service. Is this the best/easiest method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes - WCF is probably the simplest solution to communication between the WinForms client and the Service back-end.

Your main alternatives would be:
 1. TCP sockets (lower-level and would likely require a lot more boilerplate code).
 2. Messaging middleware like MSMQ/ActiveMQ NMS (involves adding more third-party libraries)

If you go with WCF, there are a few gotchas/recommendations from my experience:

1. Instead of handling WCF requests synchronously in the server, handle them asynchronously (if you code is thread-safe), or handle them via a single background processing queue (if your code is not thread-safe). This helps avoid issues with timeouts (which can cause WCF to fault), as well as issues where the WCF requests get triggered at the same time from multiple threads.
2. Don't forget that you will likely need a WCF interface in the client as well as the server. This is needed if you want the server to be able to send any kind of async communication back to the client.
3. You can set up a pub/sub mechanism with WCF but it's a bit tricky. Here is a code example:

Interface

```
//Server interface
[ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(IGUIService))]
public interface IServerService
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void Subscribe();

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void Unsubscribe();

    ...

}

//Client interface
[ServiceContract]
public interface IGUIService
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void MessageCallback(string Message);
}
```

The client will need to call Subscribe() when it starts, and Unsubscribe() when it shuts down. The corresponding server code to handle this is:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode=InstanceContextMode.Single)]
public class ServerService : IServerService
{
    internal event SettingsUpdatedHandler SettingsUpdated;
    internal delegate void SettingsUpdatedHandler(ServerService adminPort, EventArgs e);

    private static List<IGUIService> Clients = new List<IGUIService>();

    public void Subscribe()
    {
            IGUIService callback = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IGUIService>();
            if(!Clients.Contains(callback))
                Clients.Add(callback);
    }

    public void Unsubscribe()
    {
            IGUIService callback = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IGUIService>();
            if (Clients.Contains(callback))
                Clients.Remove(callback);
    }
}
```

Then to send a message from the server to all connected clients:

```
    internal void SendMessage(string message)
    {
            for(int i=Clients.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                IGUIService callback = Clients[i];
                if (((ICommunicationObject)callback).State == CommunicationState.Opened)
                    callback.MessageCallback(message);
                else
                    Clients.RemoveAt(i);
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want you can use also [web api](http://www.asp.net/web-api).But note if use web api you can use transaction.

But both web api and  wcf is good.

Answer (score 1):

WCF server: hosted in a Windows Service in server.

WCF Client: Winform application. And put the shortcut of the program in the folder "C:\Documents and Settings[username]\Start Menu\Programs\Startup" (Windows XP). program will be run automatically when user is login.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to maintain state in the service? If not then can you not just host in IIS or self host a wcf, web api or even service stack service.   Also is the service going to be utilised by more than one client? Does the persistence store access need to live in another process, if not then "in process" would be just fine too, without the overhead of all the service related stuff.

Answer (score 1):

What you have, are two processes that need to communicate with each other. One of the processes happens to be a Windows services, while the other is a Windows application. This is a classic problem of interprocess communication. There is a number of available solutions, probably the most popular being:

1. WCF, already mentioned by you. Your Windows service implements a host for WCF services and the app communicates with the exposed service. Here's a good  [example](http://tech.pro/tutorial/855/wcf-tutorial-basic-interprocess-communication) how to implement this.
2. Named Pipes, old and preferred by many. Look [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7176/Inter-Process-Communication-in-NET-Using-Named-Pip) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546102%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for some examples.

Other, more exotic examples:

1. Custom TCP ports
2. Win32 RPC. You can use .NET wrapper like [this](http://csharptest.net/projects/rpclibrary/) library.
3. MSMQ
4. File system. One process writes to a defined location, where the other listens to. You can write simple messages understood by both sides, or even whole objects using serializtion.
5. Database. Variation of the point 4, using a third process providing database functionality.

Given that WCF is quite mature technology with a sufficient performance, built with .NET and reasonably easy to implement, this seems like a natural choice.